# Routing does not work

Tags: angular2-routing

i would like to do a routing from dashboard. But it is not working at all.
this is ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Section }        from './sections';
import { SectionService } from './section.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'dashboard.component.css' ],
  providers: [SectionService]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  sections: Section[] = [];

  constructor(private sectionService: SectionService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sectionService.getSections()
      .then(sections => this.sections = sections.slice(0, 4));
  }
}
```

and html file:

```
<h3>Sections</h3>
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <a *ngFor="let section of sections" routerLink="['/detail', section.id]" class="col-1-4">
    <div class="module section">
      <h4>{{section.name}}</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Can anybody explain what is wrong?

this is app.module.ts

```
const sectionRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'detail/:id', component: SectionDetailComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(sectionRoutes)
  ],
```

There is no any compilation error. only i click and don't receive result of routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use [routerLink] instead of routerLink:

```
<a *ngFor="let section of sections" [routerLink]="['/detail', section.id]" class="col-1-4">
<div class="module section">
  <h4>{{section.name}}</h4>
</div>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html